# How intersect two results sets?

Tags: mysql, resultset

I have two tables `library` and `book` as shown in these two blocks

```
bookid   title  author  publisher 
0        ABC    Abc     abc 
1        DEF    Def     def
2        GHI    Ghi     abc
3        ...    ...     ...

id       discount   price
0         50          8
1         75          6
2         33         10
3         ..         ..
```

I need to select each author with his work, price and discount where publisher has at least 2 titles and not more than 9.
First query might be

```
SELECT title, author, publisher, price, discount FROM library, book
```

This is cleary returning all data. The second query might be

```
SELECT publisher FROM library GROUP BY publisher 
HAVING COUNT(bookid) > 2 AND COUNT(bookid) < 9
```

This is OK but it does not return author, title and price. I would like to intersect the two result sets. I have tried with the following query

```
SELECT title, author, publisher, price, discount FROM library LEFT JOIN
book ON library.bookid = book.id WHERE publisher IN ( SELECT publisher
FROM library GROUP BY publisher HAVING COUNT(bookid) < 9 AND 
COUNT(bookid) > 2 ) ORDER BY publisher ASC
```

Output should be:

```
Title  Author  Publisher Price   Discount
ABC    Abc     abc       8       ...
GHI    Ghi     abc       10      ...
...    ...     def       11      ...
...    ...     def       11      ...
...    ...     def       9       ...
```

It works fine but it is terribly slow on 100 records and it does not work at all when there are more than 1000 records. How can I optimize my query?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What if a book has more than one author?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically your query:

```
SELECT l.title, l.author, l.publisher, b.price, b.discount
FROM library l LEFT JOIN
     book b
     ON l.bookid = b.id
WHERE l.publisher IN (SELECT l.publisher
                      FROM library l
                      GROUP BY l.publisher
                      HAVING COUNT(*) < 9 AND COUNT(*) > 3
                     )
ORDER BY l.publisher ASC;
```

First, I would move the `IN` logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT l.title, l.author, l.publisher, b.price, b.discount
FROM library l LEFT JOIN
     book b
     ON l.bookid = b.id JOIN
     (SELECT l.publisher
      FROM library l
      GROUP BY l.publisher
      HAVING COUNT(*) < 9 AND COUNT(*) > 3
     ) ll
     ON l.publisher = ll.publisher
ORDER BY l.publisher ASC;
```

Then, I think these indexes may help `book(id)`, `library(publisher, bookid)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly.  You're my hero! :)))